# woocommerce if specific product is in cart disable specific checkout fields that otherwise would be required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to write php code for woocommerce that would check if specific product is in cart and if it is true, then some checkout fields would be disabled. What I have now:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'find_product_in_cart' );

function find_product_in_cart() {
$product_id = 989; //product id which would trigger
$in_cart = false;

foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
   $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
   if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true; // checks if the product is in cart
}
    if ( $in_cart ) {
      add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'woo_filter_state_billing');
      function woo_filter_state_billing( $address_fields ) {
        //sets fields to not required
          $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_city']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
          return $address_fields;
      }

      add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'disabling' );
      function disabling($fields){
        //hides fields
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
          unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
        return $fields;
      }
    }
}
```

So the problem is that for some reason fields stay required even if hidden. If I cut out the whole:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'woo_filter_state_billing');
      function woo_filter_state_billing( $address_fields ) {
        //sets fields to not required
          $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_city']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
          $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
          return $address_fields;
      }
```

and paste it just as it is in functions.php everything works just fine, but it applies to every product and that is not good. 
So, how could I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to redo everything in a cleaner way and it works!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'disabling' );
  function disabling($fields){
    $product_id = 989; //product id which would trigger
    $in_cart = false;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
       $product_in_cart = $cart_item['product_id'];
       if ( $product_in_cart === $product_id ) $in_cart = true; // checks if the product is in cart
    }
    if ( $in_cart ){
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
      unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
      return $fields;
    }
    else {
      return $fields;
    }
  }
```

So in the end I think that unset function failed to work properly because of the top add_action:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'find_product_in_cart' );
```